# PHP: Create thumbnail of top left of picture

Tags: php, thumbnails, pixel, dimensions

I have this large png file and now I want to create a thumbnail of the upper left corner.

The png is like 600x1000 pixels, the thumbnail should be top left 400x300 pixels of it.

Would be awesome if you can help me out! (Since google only shows how to thumbnail the ENTIRE picture)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
imagecopyresampled( $top_left_image_thumb,       //cropped thumbnail image
                    $original_image,             //original image
                    0, 0, 0, 0,                  //top-left corners
                    $thumb_width, $thumb_height, //dst dimensions 
                    400, 300                     //src subarea dimensions
                   );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use imagecopyresampled function in PHP to copy part of a source image and also scale it to any size you want.

Please check the PHP documentation for the function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php